# Problems while concatenating string columns into a new column with pandas?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
colA      ColB 
orange    NaN
apple     red apples   
NaN       fruit        
...       ...          
tomato    tomato
```

I am interested in concatenating `ColA` and `ColB` into a new column (`ColC`), the problem is that when I do:

```
df["ColC"] = df["ColA"].map(str) + df["ColB"]
```

I get:

```
colA      ColB         ColC
orange    NaN          orangenan
apple     red apples   applered apples
NaN       fruit        nanfruit
...       ...          ...
tomato    tomato       tomatotomato
```

How can I handle, repeated strings, nans and adding different strings separated by commas?, for example the expected output should be:

```
colA      ColB         ColC
orange    NaN          orange
apple     red apples   apple, red apples
NaN       fruit        fruit
...       ...          ...
tomato    tomato       tomato
```

**UPDATE**

After trying @MaxU solution:

```
df["ColC"] = df[["ColA","ColB"].fillna('').astype(str).sum(1)
```

I am still having problems for:

```
apple     red apples   applered apples
```

Since the string is not separated by commas:

```
apple     red apples   apple, red apples
```

Any idea of how to get the string separated by commas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df["ColC"] = df["ColA"].fillna('').astype(str) + df["ColB"].fillna('').astype(str)
```

or:

```
df["ColC"] = df[["ColA","ColB"]].fillna('').astype(str).sum(1)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
cols = ['ColA','ColB']

In [94]: df['ColC'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().unique()), axis=1)

In [95]: df
Out[95]:
     ColA        ColB               ColC
0  orange         NaN             orange
1   apple  red apples  apple, red apples
2     NaN       fruit              fruit
3  tomato      tomato             tomato
```

Comment: I tried the first one and still has the nan issues. Thanks max!

Comment: The second one works well!.. However is not adding commas for `apple     red apples   applered apples`

Comment: Thanks max!... The issue is that I actually have more than 3 columns (I just omitted them for space issues), So I tried to: `df['ColC'] = df['ColC'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().unique()), axis=1)` and got: `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`.

Comment: @tumbleweed, you can specify list columns that must be concatenated - see updated answer...